# Issue with thread safety- Not getting the answer expected

Tags: java, thread-safety

I am attempting to add up
a sequence of double precision floating point numbers which are given as Strings in an
array. The addition of these numbers is carried out in a separate background thread.
Running the code calculates the sum of the array of numbers and also gives the time that
the system took to calculate this in seconds.

I am not sure how to implement synchronization and conditional synchronization to this class:

```
public class SerialAdder implements Adder {
    private String[] values;
    private double sum;
    private boolean ready = false;

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            sum = 0.0;

            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                sum = sum + Double.valueOf(values[i]);
            }

            ready = true;
        }
    }

    public synchronized void setValues(String[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public synchronized void setThreads(int threads) {
        // This does nothing since this is the single-threaded version.
    }

    public synchronized double getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

This should not be changed but is here for reference.

```
public interface Adder extends Runnable {

    void setValues(String[] values);
    void setThreads(int threads);
    double getSum();
}
```

This is the main

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    /**
     * All this data is "statistically initialized" and hence visibility to all threads in the running application.
     */
    private static final String[] DATA1 = {"1.0", "2.0", "3.0", "4.0"};
    private static final String[] DATA2 = {"100000000000000000000.0", "-100000000000000000000.0", "1.0", "2.0"};
    private static final String[] DATA3 = {"1.0", "2.0", "100000000000000000000.0", "-100000000000000000000.0"};

    /**
     * This is an Example of more complex "static initialization" that guarantees data visibility to all threads.
     */

    private static final String[] DATA4;

    static {

        /*** TASK3: CHANGE THIS VALUE SO THAT YOUR COMPUTER TAKES SEVERAL SECONDS FOR THE SERIAL CASE ***/
        final int POWER = 10;
        final int N = (int)Math.pow(2, POWER);
        DATA4 = new String[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            DATA4[i] = String.valueOf(1.0/N);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        // Start the timer ...
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        /*** TASK 2 - CHANGE THIS LINE TO SEE HOW THE CODE BEHAVES WITH DIFFERENT DATA INPUTS. ***/
        String[] values = DATA1;


        /*** TASK 3 - CHANGE THE FOLLOWING SINGLE LINE TO CHANGE TO USING A MULTITHREADED VERSION OF THE ADDER. ***/

        // This is an example of "programming to an interface" ... so only a single line
        // needs to be changed to change the implementation used in the rest of the code.

        Adder adder = new SerialAdder(); // = MultithreaderAdder();
        adder.setValues(values);

        new Thread(adder).start();

        System.out.println("Answer = " + adder.getSum());

        // Printed answer ... stop the timer.
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Nanoseconds to seconds ...
        System.out.println("Time = " + (endTime - startTime)/1000.0 + " seconds.") ;

    }
}
```

And the multithreaded adder:

```
public class MultithreadedAdder implements Adder {

    public void run() {};

    public void setValues(String[] values) {};

    public void setThreads(int threads) {};

    public double getSum() {
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

I am using the current data  {“1.0”, “2.0”, “3.0”, “4.0”} and so expect answer of 10.0 however I am getting 0.

Comment: **"Not getting the answer expected"** ... what answer do you get and what did you expect? You also missed how you run your code, what values are given and especially how you construct your threads.

Comment: Yes you are correct, my apologies Ill add it now.

Comment: The issue is fixed

Comment: What do you want to achieve? That the calculation as such is done in a background thread? Then you should have a look to `Future`. – Or do you want to parallelise the calculation (multiple threads contributing to the result)? In that case you should have a look to `Stream`.

Comment: You shouldn't call `System.out.println("Answer = " + adder.getSum())` right after starting a thread, or different: you shouldn't assume your thread already has calculated the sum when you call `getSum()` right after starting it

Comment: Is there any changes you could recommend adding to SerialAdder in order to make it more threadsafe?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest some simplifications:

1. Drop the `Adder` interface.  Implement the `Callable` interface instead.  It allows you to return a value.
2. I'd advise against the `setThreads()` method.   Give your `Callable` instance to a pooled `Executor`.
3. If one of those Strings in the array does not parse as a `Double` your sum will fail.  What do you plan to do about it?  I'd have a try/catch block.

   ```
   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

   public class DoubleStreamAdder implements Callable<Double> {

       private final String [] values;

       public DoubleStreamAdder(final String [] v) {
           this.values = new String[v.length];
           System.arraycopy(v, 0, this.values, 0, v.length);
       }

       @Override
       public Double call() throws Exception {
           return Arrays.stream(this.values).mapToDouble(Double::valueOf).sum();
       }
   }
   ```

You could do all of this using Java functional programming without the classes: see the single line in my `call()` method.   That is what you're trying to do.  The less code you write, the fewer bugs you'll have.  You can eliminate more than 17 lines of code by deleting your interface and the class and writing a *single line of code*.  *Much* better.